# How to write Eclipse BUILT in GUI

Tags: java, eclipse, user-interface, plugins

so please help me out.

So I have been creating GUI using AWT and SWING in java eclipse. 
Currently my program creates pop-up windows for the UI, with the use of JFrame and such.

I recently learned that I can create UI that is integrated in Eclipse itself. 
and doesnt need to create another window.

Is that a eclipse plugin? I am brand new to this, so please let me know where i Can learn this or if you guys can share your knowledge.

Just to make sure you guys understand, i would like to link an image. 
But just to describe, on the tabs in eclipse (TOP) where is hows the file opened currently, I want to e able to write code that opens a tab their with UI in it instead of code.

Comment: Yes that is an Eclipse plug-in. Eclipse plug-ins normally use SWT rather than Swing. Writing a plug-in is a complex task, far too broad for a StackOverflow answer.

Comment: are there any templates that I can use to get the hist of the environment? There is a hello button one, but no templates that I FOUND that produces UI and that allows me to create under a tab.

Comment: A full plug-in is far more complicated than a simple template. Read a tutorial, vogella.com has some reliable ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As greg-449 Sir clearly explained that it is bit complex and bit broad, first you have to learn the concepts of SWT and JFace as part of eclipse plugin development. To get started with, refer below the following links.

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Your%20First%20Plug-in/YourFirstPlugin.html

https://riptutorial.com/eclipse-plugin/example/25547/hello-world

https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-PDE-does-plugins/PDE-intro.html

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecplug/